# Integration tests using ApplicationFactory gives Invalid Accept header

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

We have a .NET 6 Api, (not minimal). In this api, we are requiring a specific accept header

Summary:
When I try to create a test request to an endpoint, I get the error message "406 - Invalid Accept header. When I do the same request from a console application (and keeping or api project running in Visual Studio, everything works as expected.

Code that works (from another console app)

```
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

const string acceptMediaType = "application/bla.blabla+json";
using var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(acceptMediaType));
var content = await client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:7235/api/products/");
Console.WriteLine(content);
```

Integration test that does not work ("406 - Invalid Accept header")

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test()
{
    var appFactory = new WebApplicationFactory();

    const string acceptMediaType = "application/bla.blabla+json";
    var httpClient = appFactory.CreateDefaultClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(acceptMediaType));
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("api/products/");

    var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

}
```

I have tested to just add it as a text header ["Accept", "application/bla.blabla+json"]
as well, and tested to add headers to the request object, but same error message and no details

What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your error by setting as below:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(x=> 
{    
    x.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true; 
});
```

[image]

As mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-7.0#content-negotiation-2):

> By default, ASP.NET Core supports the following media types:
>
> ```
> application/json
> text/json
> text/plain
> ```

If you want to set the Accept Header with `"application/bla.blabla+json"`

You need follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to  Custom formatters,and regist it:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(x=> 
{
    x.OutputFormatters.Add(new CusOutputFormatter());
    x.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true; 
});
```

Now,no 406 error would be thrown:

[image]

Hopes help

Comment: Not really following (not 100% sure where you are adding "x.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;"). My application already supports "application/bla.blabla+json". I  can call it from the console app (and swagger) and it works ok.

Comment: If you didn't add other custome output formats ,it only support the three media types mentioned by default, your could try  application/json  instead of  application/bla.blabla+json and observe if 406 occors

Comment: Or you could just provide a minimal example that could reproduce your issue

Comment: We (in our project) are dependent on corporate wide packages, that I cant share.  But we use 

 [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(Response.SuccessResponse<Response.Product>))]
as attibutes on our controllers

Comment: The attribute [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(Response.SuccessResponse<Response.Product>))]  is used to describe response types, check this doc related:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#describe-response-types

Comment: it dosen't have relationship with the issue

Comment: It seem to have. If I change this attribute to for example
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(Response.SuccessResponse<Response.Customer>))]

It will give me 406 - Not Acceptable - error (when calling from console app)